# Como fazer uma chamada soap no .Net Core

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-core, soap, .net-core

Estou tentando consumir um serviço externo que recebe um xml soap, mas sempre retorna erro 500 (internal server error). Porém se eu testo via SOAPUI funciona normalmente.

Testei diversos tipos de chamada e nenhuma funciona. Alguém saberia o que pode ser, ou como fazer da maneira correta?

no .net core, criei uma api para receber os dados e converter no objeto xml e chamar esse serviço externo.
então configurei a api com xmlformatters

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

minha 1a tentativa foi essa

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
    .Accept
    .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));

var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    RequestUri = new Uri(apiUrl),
    Method = HttpMethod.Post
};

httpRequest.Content = new StringContent(xml.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

httpRequest.Headers.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
httpRequest.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest).Result;
```

minha 2a tentativa foi:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"));
```

ja tentei outras formas também. nenhum funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo que funciona tanto em .net framework quanto em .net core.

```
string url = "";
string body = "";
string soapAction = "";
string soapXml = $@"<soap:Envelope 
                    xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
                    xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""
                    xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                    <soap:Body>
                      {body}
                    </soap:Body>
                  </soap:Envelope>";


WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(url);    
byte[] buff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soapXml);    
wr.Timeout = 60000;
wr.Method = "POST";
wr.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
wr.ContentLength = buff.Length;
wr.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", soapAction);

using (var reqStream = wr.GetRequestStream())
{
    reqStream.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
}

using var resp = wr.GetResponse();
using var respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
using var reader = new StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8);
var resposta = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: deu erro interno 500 tb

Comment: -- edit --  na verdade o seu codigo funciona. fiz um teste de uma chama de exemplo de um site qualquer e realmente funcionou. o problema deve estar no meu xml de envio. obrigado.